# Drawing a circle on a bufferedImage in Java

Tags: java

I want to draw a circle on a buffered image that act like a png

i want to use this circle in order to replace the mouse cursor for a paint application i am working on.

i cant download a circle png from google as i need to keep changing the size of this circle depending on the width of the tool i am using it for.

here is my attempt so far

```
  public static BufferedImage getCircle() {

    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(30, 30, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Color transparent = new Color(0x00FFFFFF, true);

    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) bufferedImage.getGraphics();
    //trying to make the bufferedImage transparent 
    g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
    g.setColor(transparent);
    g.setBackground(transparent);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight());
    //drawing the circle 
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawOval(0, 0, 200, 200);
    return bufferedImage;
}
```

it should look like:

[image]

However my code currently only creates a **white square**.

Comment: ... and how does it currently look like? I.e. why is your attempt not successful?

Comment: i should add that this code just give me a white square

Comment: Of course. You're drawing a 200x200 circle in a 30x30 image. A 30x30 corner square of the 200x200 circle is just blank space.

Comment: ok that made it better, i can see the circle but the background of the bufferImage is not transparent

Comment: Change to `TYPE_INT_ARGB`. The `A` is "Alpha", aka transparency.

Comment: wow that made it a lot better, it works pretty well when the color is black. if i change it to another color it seems like it has black spots around the circumference. Not really an issue but any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: I don't get black artifacts when changing the color. Maybe an issue with antialiasing. Do you also get it after increasing the stroke thickness? You can also set some rendering options to sacrifice speed for more quality.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has two problems (as already shown in the comments). The first is that you draw a circle with a **radius** of `200px` into an image of **dimensions** `30px`. If you closely look you can barely see a black pixel in the lower right corner.

Fix it by adjusting your dimensions such that it fits inside, for example like:

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(60, 60, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
...
g.drawOval(5, 5, 50, 50);
```

Next is that you want to achieve a transparent background. To do so you need to set the **type** of the image to a **color model which supports transparency**, like `ARGB` (A = Alpha = transparency) instead of `RGB`:

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(60, 60, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
```

Last you probably want to **increase the thickness of your border** to achieve the image you showed. You do so by using `g.setStroke(...)`:

```
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
g.drawOval(5, 5, 50, 50);
```

With this setting you achieve the following result (with transparency):

[image: resulting circle]

Play with the values to adjust the circle to your exact needs.